# About CPU undervolting

Tags: cpu

I've recently downloaded the Intel Prossecor Diagnostic Tool to do some stress tests. And they failed because of the undervolt I did with ThrottleStop on my CPU (-100mV do not pass stress test). Is it a good tactic to start from 0 V, reduce the volts little by little and do stress tests, until I find something stable (I guess -85mV should pass stress tests)? If not, which tactic is best to ensure my laptop will be stable? I'm a bit scared seeing it crashes that's why I'm asking, even tho I know undervolt does not causes fatal errors (except going for the minimum volts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test CPU stability, the preferred tool is [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/). 12-24 hours is a good test. If it survives that, it'll survive anything else you can throw at it.

Worst case, it BSOD's or reboots.

Best case, it runs for a solid period without issue.

Comment: I have 500Gb SSD Samsung EVO 860, 1TB HDD, 20GB Ram DDR4, Intel i5 7200u and Intel HD graphics 620 (the last one is really bad). Is it a good idea to download and run stress tests on prime95? I'm a bit scared for some reason. Maybe it's the bsod I've seen today:P

Comment: Is it okay if it bsod's? I mean, will it remain on this state or it will reboot after the bluescreen? Because if it reboots every time after the blue screen, then it's not scary at all. But if it doesn't I don't wanna "risk it"...what do you suggest?

Comment: You asked how to soak-test your under volt, and I answered that. But to follow up on your comment question; It should show the blue screen for ~30 seconds, and then reboot. Alternatively, you just hold the power button down until it switches off.

Comment: Oh ok I see! Thanks for the reply too!